# Guitar Recording

Tags: software-recommendation, music

I am a musician and I am fairly new to Ubuntu. I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on a Dell Inspiron 6000. I have been looking for a reliable and good mixer/recorder for my guitar so I can record original stuff. I have tried audacity and ardour both with and without front end programs such as rakarrack. The problem I am having is that I have a lot of distortin when I am playing clean and an obvious 60 hz hum when I am both clean and distorted. I've tried plugging in my guitar directly into the USB interface that I have and that doesn't help. I have also used a Boss DS-1 distortion pedal and a Marshall MG15DFX as a preamp before the USB interface as well with no luck. I can't seem to get the preamp on the programs adjusted. The USB interface I am using is a Behringer UCG102 Guitar/USB interface Guitar Link. Does anyone have any suggestions for me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I record my guitar using Ardour, it has full pre-amp sliders and gain control so you should be able to get the clean unprocessed sound you require. I DI into an old sound blaster Live sound card as its a bit retro in its sampling and gives me a nice sound for the type of music i play, but I have also set it up on Ubuntu for Musician fiend with a Black Box usb input, the only difference was when selecting the channel input on the Ardour track I selected the USB sound card as opposed to the internal one.
Hope this helps. Ardour is in the software centre.
Hope this helps, Good luck

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a try and see if I can figure out the preamp settings.